# How Exactly Do You Define Truth?

Tags: epistemology, truth

I've been trying to learn about the multiple theories of truth and I've taken a look at the popular [Stanford article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth/). The first section has this to say about the neo-classical theories of truth:

> These theories all attempt to directly answer the nature question: what is the nature of truth? They take this question at face value: there are truths, and the question to be answered concerns their nature.

This confuses me. My understanding was always that "truth" is the nature of things. Truth is the way things are. How do we ask the question, "What is the nature of truth?" It is like asking, "What is the nature of the nature of things?" If anyone could provide me with some insight I would appreciate it.

Comment: It may just answered or elaborated on your concern right after your quote: *In answering this question, each theory makes the notion of truth part of a more thoroughgoing metaphysics or epistemology. Explaining the nature of truth becomes an application of some metaphysical system, and truth inherits significant metaphysical presuppositions along the way.* In summary truth emerges only after more thorough philosophy is gained, from East to West everyone has their own intuitive idiosyncratic notion of truth, thus its *nature* is highly dependent on ones' entire metaphysical or epistemic system.

Comment: That is the "natural" understanding of Truth: a statement is True if things are the way it says they are, if it corresponds to facts. See Correspondence Theory of Truth.

Comment: It looks like you are thinking of "truth" as a sort of ephemeral, unattached stuff. In philosophy, truth is more specific; truth is a property of certain kinds of things such as sentences, propositions, beliefs, etc. Truth has to be attached to something. Think of "what is the nature of truth" as "what is it that makes a proposition true?" or "what sort of thing makes a belief true?"

Comment: For a specific example, say you posted a question, then received some answer(s) and even accepted one. On a correspondent surface, it seems *it's true you found an answer for your question*. But for someone else if they see you still think/act in old ways/habits when cases applicable to said question arise in other situations, *it's perhaps more true that you didn't find an answer for the said question*. There's no inconsistency here though the truth of the same proposition in dependent on different people. For some like Heidegger truth is extremely hidden without any easy correspondence...

Comment: There are two main types of truth in epistemology: objective truths & contingent truths.  Objective truth is a constant which never changes.  Once a proposition is true it is always true forever. The same goes for propositions that are false. They will forever be false if they are objective. Now you are probably thinking most truths are not like that! That is why there are contingent truths. These truths are temporary. They can be true today and be false a day later.  The weather could be snowing today and not snowing tomorrow. The truth will alternative true to false at various points in time

Comment: @Logikal I see. But ultimately, contingent truths are also "objective" in a sense if I specify the time or other conditions in respect to which it is contingent, no?

Comment: If you are super specific in your details about something it becomes a proposition. A proposition is objectively true or false in epistemology.  Once you are precise then your proposition is just objectively true. You don't convert from contingent to objective truth. What people in reality do differs from what I am saying here. They purposely omit details that may make a conclusion seem to go there way. People may omit details that would otherwise go against their desires. So they say this is a case by case basis. Then common practice implies truth varies & is not clear,  or undefinable.

Comment: @Logikal I understand. I'm more interested in the nature of things than how exactly people perceive it and I generally don't have trouble catching people when they're trying to BS things in their direction :]

Comment: I stopped taking Philosophy courses when I saw that the roads of "how things are" and "how we talk about things" seemed to part ways. This was further accelerated by the multiplicity of "ways to talk about things". Then there were the folks who made it clear that we could never actually know - be in touch with directly - how things are, and I said, "let me know when you figure it out!" And that's the news from lake misbegotten. Sorry that there is not a better answer. Perhaps try nonduality instead?

Comment: @ScottRowe I am actually already quite spiritual and nondualism is something I consider deeply. It's just for the sake of conversation and mathematics I try to have very concrete stances on such things.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the truth itself is the way things are, and like you're saying, there isn't so much we can do to further define that. It just is.

But there's a second consideration, which is that humans make *claims* about the way things are. These claims may be considered as sequences of characters, or noises, or perhaps patterns of mental activity. And we call some of these claims true, and other claims false. So, what grants this attribute of truth, to a sequence of characters or noises? That's the question of truth that philosophers are mostly concerned with.

If the dog is out in the yard, (an actual, true state of affairs), then the verbal claim, "The dog is outside," is true. There's some relationship between the verbal claim (coming out of your mouth), and the actual state of affairs (in the yard); what is that relationship?

Personally, I subscribe to the perspective that a claim is true if a reasonable person would eventually settle on it, if he were able to investigate all the relevant evidence pro or con, and think for long enough.

Comment: I see. So are you essentially saying that this is more a discussion of how people try to reach and express Truth more so than what exactly it is?

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to causative 's excellent answer, which pithily gets to the gist of the matter, here is a pretty succinct outline of the overwhelmingly and timelessly prevalent traditional correspondence theory of truth, as well as its two most traditionally popular competitors:

> *The Correspondence Theory of Truth*:   The Correspondence Theory of
> Truth is probably the most common and widespread way of understanding
> the nature of truth and falsehood. Put quite simply, the
> Correspondence Theory argues that “truth” is whatever corresponds to
> reality. An idea which corresponds with reality is true while an idea
> which does not correspond with reality is false. It is important to
> note here that “truth” is not a property of “facts.” This may seem odd
> at first, but a distinction is being made here between facts and
> beliefs. A fact is some set of circumstances in the world while a
> belief is an opinion about those what those facts are. A fact cannot
> be either true or false, it simply is because that is the way the
> world is. A belief, however, is capable of being true or false because
> it may or may not accurately describe the world.   Under the
> Correspondence Theory of Truth, the reason why we label certain
> beliefs as “true” is because they correspond to those facts about the
> world. Thus, the belief that the sky is blue is a “true” belief
> because of the fact that the sky is blue. Along with beliefs, we can
> count statements, propositions, sentences, etc. as capable of being
> true or false.

Especially after Kant’s distinction between noumena (things in themselves) and phenomena (the world of appearances; perceptions and apperceptions), in his Transcendental Idealism (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-transcendental-idealism/), and the purported failure of traditional “Realism” (*tout court*, or in this or that domain), it became impossible to make/have non-inferential/mediated claims/beliefs about an “objective” world (noumena/things in themselves), a so called view from nowhere.  So, competing theories about the nature[lessness] of truth were developed, the most traditionally popular of which were:

> *The Coherence Theory of Truth*:   The Coherence Theory of truth is
> probably second in popularity to the Correspondence Theory even though
> it often seems to be an accurate description of how our conception of
> truth actually works. Put simply: a belief is true when we are able to
> incorporate it in an orderly and logical manner into a larger and
> complex system of beliefs or, even more simply still, a belief is true
> when it fits in with the set of all our other beliefs without creating
> a contradiction.

> *The Pragmatic Theory of Truth*:  The Pragmatic Theoryof truth determines whether or not a belief is true or not based on whether it has a useful (pragmatic) application in the world. If it > does not, then it is not true. As with Coherence Theory, truth in this > sense is nothing to do with the way the world ‘really is’ but is just a function of whether an idea can be used as a model to make useful predictions about what is going to happen in the world. As a result pragmatic truths can only be learnt through interaction with the > world: we don’t discover truth by sitting alone in a room and thinking about it.

But particularly over the last Century+ there have developed many increasingly "deflationary" theories of [no longer capital T]  truth (including Causative’s preferred theory, developed by C.S. Pierce, and elucidated further by Hillary Putnum):

> Deflationary theories of Truth:  Deflationism about truth, what is
> often simply called “deflationism”, is really not so much a theory of
> truth in the traditional sense, as it is a different, newer sort of
> approach to the topic. Traditional theories of truth are part of a
> philosophical debate about the nature of a supposed property of truth.
> Philosophers offering such theories often make suggestions like the
> following: truth consists in correspondence to the facts; truth
> consists in coherence with a set of beliefs or propositions; truth is
> what is acceptable in the ideal limit of inquiry. According to
> deflationists, such suggestions are mistaken, and, moreover, they all
> share a common mistake. The common mistake is to assume that truth has
> a nature of the kind that philosophers might find out about and
> develop theories of. The main idea of the deflationary approach is (a)
> that all that can be significantly said about truth is exhausted by an
> account of the role of the expression ‘true’ or of the concept of
> truth in our talk and thought, and (b) that, by contrast with what
> traditional views assume, this role is neither metaphysically
> substantive nor explanatory. For example, according to deflationary
> accounts, to say that ‘snow is white’ is true, or that it is true that
> snow is white, is in some sense strongly equivalent to saying simply
> that snow is white, and this, according to the deflationary approach,
> is all that can be said significantly about the truth of ‘snow is
> white’. Philosophers looking for some underlying nature of some truth
> property that is attributed with the use of the expression ‘true’ are
> bound to be frustrated, the deflationist says, because they are
> looking for something that isn’t there.
> https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-deflationary/.

(Also see, *inter alia* for instance, *Lynch’s Truth in Context*, and Blackburn’s *Truth a Guide*
[https://www.amazon.com/Truth-Context-Essay-Pluralism-Objectivity/dp/026262155X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/026262155X)
[https://www.amazon.com/Truth-Guide-Simon-Blackburn-ebook/dp/B00UNRO9HA/ref=sr_1_2?crid=2M9PURIKQ1LEQ&keywords=truth+a+guide&qid=1645386306&s=books&sprefix=truth+a+guide%2Cstripbooks%2C147&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UNRO9HA)).

Is it any wonder that we live in a “post-truth” world amongst a plethora of competing “alternative facts,” where, “chimera” like “reality,” “the world,” “objective facts” etc. are no longer non-naively believed to constrain what can be claimed or believed?  Where "knowledge" itself is up for grabs.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused but I often wonder why we posited 'beliefs' at all and didn't simply stick with facts. If we don't know something, we should say, "I don't know" and if we turn out to be wrong, well, we were wrong.

Comment: @Scott Rowe   I "believe" that I comprehend each and every one of your terms, and even how they fit together in your sentences, But without more [preciser?] context, your comment is more of an enigma to me than anything else.   Are you asking why we do not always use/say, "I don't know" period.  And eliminate the "...yet/but I believe..." part"    If so, why so, what would be the benefit of such a linguistic custom/norm.     Sounds to me that it would be even more of a conversation stopper than inserting, say, God as one's authority for claiming to know something.

Comment: Sorry, I guess this is why I should stay out of Philosophy. I regret having been a bother.

Comment: @Scott Rowe A "bother", cmon, bro, chill.  Was my response to your comment too "pedantic?" or what?   Your comment was very interesting to me.   Give me a break.  We may both learn something.    "Bothers" in the case of considering what it means to "exist" or "know" are two of my favorite things to ponder.   Just give me a clue as to what you mean by "I often wonder why we posited 'beliefs' at all and didn't simply stick with facts."  Who's "we," and what do you mean by "facts."    We talking "objective facts,"  or the whole standpoint (my truth/your truth) situated knowledge thing?

Comment: Ok, I mean Beliefs in the large sense, things like Religion. Philosophy and Math churn out a lot also: ideas that can't really be verified, what Science calls 'unfalsifiable', or casually: "not even wrong". If people are uncomfortable with the inevitability of death, I empathize, but creating a bureaucracy is not the answer. If we 'know' something, say it. I guess this is reminiscent of Stoicism? I only have one belief that I accept "without sufficient evidence".

Comment: @Scott Rowe  I will presume that in your original comment you are referring to the answer’s description of the “correspondence” theory, which distinguishes between facts and beliefs:  “A fact is some set of circumstances in the world while a belief is an opinion about those what those facts are. A fact cannot be either true or false, it simply is because that is the way the world is. A belief, however, is capable of being true or false bc it may or may not accurately describe the world.”  And you ask: “why we posited 'beliefs' at all and didn't simply stick with “facts.”   Two issues arise...

Comment: First, how then do we discuss/converse about things like, as you mention, religion, or better, art/aesthetics (putting aside talk about medium [concatenation of notes, application of paint/hue, etc..   Or are you speaking strictly phenomenologically? That is, it is a [phenomenological]  “fact” [not a ”belief”] that I experience/feel [have the qualia/mental state described as] delight, arousal, sorrow, pain, anguish etc. [aside from whatever my neurons are doing]  when confronted by a Beethoven Sonata or Basquiat painting…

Comment: Second, it is now commonly held that all facts/perceptions are theory laden – that is, affected by the theoretical presuppositions held by the perceiver/believer/investigator.   And theories are sets of beliefs [or propositions or sentences] which are to a greater or lesser extent verifiable/falsifiable...

Comment: So, [D.P. Moynihan’s] old saw that everyone is entitled to their own opinions [beliefs] but not to their own facts is no longer a regnant, b/c the distinction between a “fact of the matter,” and a “belief/opinion” is considered to be ambiguous.  The consequence of which is outlined in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Well, my response would be: given that we can't always know facts, then rather than trying to distinguish fact from belief and going on to develop elaborate systems of those beliefs, simply say, "this is the best I can do." And go forward to succeed or fail with your best attempt. No self-justification, no props, no insurance... Bet and roll and that's it.